# FloatBuffer throwing exception? How can I fix this?

Tags: java, lwjgl

Code:

```
FloatBuffer buf = BufferTools.reserveData(4);
float[] fl = new float[]{0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f};
buf.put(fl);
```

where `buf.put(fl)` is line 2039 that the error is talking about:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Number of remaining buffer elements is 0, must be at least 4. Because at most 4 elements can be returned, a buffer with at least 4 elements is required, regardless of actual returned element count
    at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.throwBufferSizeException(BufferChecks.java:162)
    at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkBufferSize(BufferChecks.java:189)
    at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkBuffer(BufferChecks.java:258)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glLight(GL11.java:2039)
    at Joehot200.TerrainDemo.setUpLighting(TerrainDemo.java:1543)
    at Joehot200.TerrainDemo.enterGameLoop(TerrainDemo.java:1984)
    at Joehot200.TerrainDemo.startGame(TerrainDemo.java:2109)
    at Joehot200.Main.main(Main.java:56)
```

What am I doing wrong? I would just like to have a FloatBuffer with 4 elements in it so that I can set the OpenGL ambient lighting.

Comment: What is at TerrainDemo:2109, 1984, and 1543?

Comment: So the code you are showing us is from `org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11` and not your own code?

Comment: BufferTools isn't a `org.lwggl` API.  Where does it come from?

Comment: Also, why use `BufferTools`? `FloatBuffer.allocate(N)` does the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LWJGL throws this error it the buffer is too small for the requested operation. See [here](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/master/src/java/org/lwjgl/BufferChecks.java#L189)

My guess is that `BufferTools.reserveData(4)` reserves 4 byte and not 4*sizeof(float) == 16 byte.